# Can jOOQ generate code for Oracle synonyms?

Tags: java, code-generation, jooq, synonym

My team has been experimenting [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) and it looks effective. However, we have to consume some Oracle synonyms which are referring to some Oracle views. We were able to consume the views but we need to consume it through the synonyms. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of jOOQ (jOOQ 3.8.1), this is not possible. It is on the roadmap, however:

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1563